# Can't figure out how to change my scrollbar colors in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, colors, themes, scrollbar, settings

I'm trying to use Visual Studio Color Theme Editor to make my own theme for visual studio 2010.

As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvHf0.png), I've gotten most of my theme set up, however the scrollbars are still very light colored.

I cannot figure out how to change the scrollbar colors.

In the edit colors dialog, I have changed all scrollbar related colors to crazy rainbow colors but have not seen any change. ([pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRXR7.png))

I can't stand having everything dark except for the scroll bars, does anyone know how I can change the colors?

Comment: This might answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623370/visual-studio-2015-change-right-vertical-scroll-bar-indicator-colors

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get a slightly better scroll bar button with these settings in Visual Studio Ultimate 2013.

Go to:
Text Editor > All Languages > Scrollbars
Under Display, uncheck 'Show annotations over vertical scrollbar'
Under Behavior:
Check 'Use map mode for vertical scroll bar'
Uncheck 'Show Preview Tooltip'
Set Source Preview to Off

This gives a white button with a black outline on my system, a little better contrast. One downside is that is gets small if you have a huge code file.

Comment: You can also go there by just right clicking on scroll bar and and select "Scroll bar options".

Comment: Thanks for the tip, very helpful. Now, how do I toggle word wrap in one-click? :)

Answer (score -2):

Go to

> Tools>Options>Text Editor>All Languages>Scroll Bars > "Your Activity..."

Comment: This only allows you to enable the enhanced scrollbar. There are no settings on this screen to change colors.