# Visual Studio 2015 - change right vertical scroll bar indicator colors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I use a dark color theme and the breakpoints and search results are hard to tell apart (orange and red).  Is there any way to change the colors?

Comment: My god, I was going insane. I wanted to use dark theme, but this color scheme for Breakpoint and Search is infuriating af.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can change the colors by going to the Tools menu -> Options then go to Environment -> Fonts and Colors:

For the breakpoint line: Breakpoint (Scroll bar)

[image]

And for the find result: Find Match Highlight

[image]

And the result (bright red for the breakpoint and Lime for search results):

[image]