# Visual studio 2017 change color of selected references in vertical scroll

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, syntax-highlighting

how can I change the color that are shown in the right vertical scrollbar when I click on a variable (or class, or whatever), that shown all the references to the same variable?

[image]

Now the color is purple, I would like to change it.

I've already changed some colors, but I can not find this one.  :(

Thank you! :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623370/visual-studio-2015-change-right-vertical-scroll-bar-indicator-colors

Comment: Thank you Hans Passant, but I know where the settings is, but I can't find the right value to change.